# How to put a MapView inside of a ScrollView?

Tags: ios, react-native

I noticed that it appears to be impossible to put a MapView inside of a ScrollView. I imagine it's because iOS doesn't want me to have a scrollable object inside another scrollable object. The thing is, I don't necessarily need the MapView to be interactive at all. Is there some way I can just display a static map based on some coordinates, and then tapping it could use LinkingIOS to open up Maps?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the mapView's `scrollEnabled` and `zoomEnabled` properties to `false`. You'll notice Apple's own apps do this, so it's totally allowed.

To intercept the tap either attach a UITapGestureRecognizer to the map view or put a transparent view in front of it with a tap gesture recognizer attached to that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just display a map, why not use Google statics maps interface and just display an image https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps ?

Comment: seems easier to use a map view? plus MKMapView is iOS's native map widget--so you'll get an iOS standard map appearance. etc.

Comment: easier because he uses react native, so it would be just :
 <Image        source={{uri: 'IMAGE_URL'}}       />

For the mapview he might need to touch native code or write your own component.

Comment: @nielsbot but i agree native might look better.

Comment: oh I missed that this was using React

Answer (score 0):

Well, that was dumb! The MapView was not displaying because it needed a specific height. The `flex: 1` style applied to it worked fine when it was outside the ScrollView, but had no effect once it was moved within it.

Comment: Setting height does not get the job done for me. Could you share that section of the code, to see if I'm missing something else ??

Answer (score 0):

I too came across this issue. Yes, while the answer about setting a specific height is one solution, I found another solution. You can use the `vh` unit to style the `MapView` component, like this:

`<ScrollView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <MapView style={{ height: 34 * vh }}/>
</ScrollView>`

**However**, `vh` is not supported by default, so you can use [this package](https://github.com/jmstout/react-native-viewport-units). Another caveat is that currently this package seems not to be maintained or working (due to an import issue). You can however copy the `index.js` file directly into your application and import the `vh` unit for use.

Hope this helps others!